# Having trouble inserting a row in a DB table when running a stored procedure which is using the same table in another transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let me explain my problem. I have data warehouse stored procedure which used link server to connect to 3 different database and get data. But when warehouse import is running which is under a transaction then it blocks 3 tables in those 3 database. So as the import run for at least 3 hours the main sites gets blocked.

Now when the import is running, people trying to access the site gets stuck as one of the action was to insert a entry in the history table which is getting blocked. But should it block insert operation when there is a select query in another SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

If you use WITH(NOLOCK) option during the retrieval, SQL Server wont block other users from inserting data